# apt-get upgrade 後「504 Gateway Time-out」エラーが出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx

多くの基本的な事を理解せず、見まね物まねでruby on rails でアプリケーションを作り、ubuntuで自宅サーバーを立て、Nginxでウエブに公開している者です。

ずっと問題なく一応アプリは稼働していたのですが、昨日(1/17) 急にエラーメッセージ に「504 Gateway Time-out」が出てきてネットからアクセス不可能になりました。

`apt-get update ; apt-get upgrade`を実行した後このメッセージが出始めました。今までずっと`apt-get update ; apt-get upgrade`は問題なくできていました。

【ubuntu環境】

```
root@****:~# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
```

【nginxエラーログ】

```
/var/log/nginx/error.log

018/01/18 17:31:56 [error] 1236#1236: *20 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream
, client: 192.168.210.4, server: 192.168.210.150, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/nagao/run/app_nagao2.
```

【nginxバージョン】

```
root@****:~# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
```

【nginx設定】
/etc/nginx/conf.d/app_nagao2.conf

```
upstream app_nagao2 {
    server unix:/home/nagao/run/app_nagao2.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.210.150;

    root /home/nagao/run/app_nagao2/public; # アプリケーション名を記述

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app_nagao2; # アプリケーション名を記述

    location /{
        proxy_pass http://app_nagao2; # アプリケーション名を記述
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

ruby on rails は問題なく動いているようでエラーログも出ていません。
何か問題があるようでしたら教えてください(明日から3日ぐらいアクセスできません)。

【追加部分】
遅れて申し訳ありません。
一応自分でテストできた事は下記です。

ファイル：/etc/nginx/nginx.confの中を下記の様に一部変更しました。

```
   include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
#  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;=>コメントアウトしたのですがうまく表示されません。
```

これはユーザー設定ファイル(/etc/nginx/conf.d/app_nagao2.conf)を読ませないと言うことです。  
結果は「Welcome to Nginx」なので take88さんが言われているようにNginxには問題無いのではないかと思います。通常は反対で(include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;)行をコメントアウトしています。

次に下記ファイル(~/bin/run_app_nagao.sh)のpumaの引数 -d を取り除いて対話形式で`run_app_nagao.sh`を実行したところ、pumaのバージョンが低いようなメッセージがでました(すみません、ログは取っていません)。
pumaのバージョンを上げて(3.11.?=>忘れました)app_nagao2のvendor以下のファイルを削除して`bunndle install --path vendor/bundle`で実行したところ、今度はわけのわからないほどエラーでました。(すみません、これもログを取っていません。)
それで`gem update`を実行してpumaのバージョンは最新のものだけにして`bundle install`して実行しましたがやはりエラーわんさかです。エラーログ、必要ありそうなファイルを下記に挙げました。これで何かわかるでしょうか？
ちなみにdevelopment環境(rails s -b 0.0.0.0)では正常に稼働しているように見えます。

---

```
xxxx@yyyyy:~/bin$ ./run_app_nagao.sh
[1563] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[1563] * Version 3.11.2 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Love Song
[1563] * Min threads: 8, max threads: 8
[1563] * Environment: production
[1563] * Process workers: 8
[1563] * Phased restart available
[1563] * Listening on unix:///home/nagao/run/app_nagao2.sock
[1563] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[1593] + Gemfile in context: /home/nagao/run/app_nagao2/Gemfile
[1597] + Gemfile in context: /home/nagao/run/app_nagao2/Gemfile
[1601] + Gemfile in context: /home/nagao/run/app_nagao2/Gemfile
[1607] + Gemfile in context: /home/nagao/run/app_nagao2/Gemfile
[1605] + Gemfile in context: /home/nagao/run/app_nagao2/Gemfile
[1613] + Gemfile in context: /home/nagao/run/app_nagao2/Gemfile
[1617] + Gemfile in context: /home/nagao/run/app_nagao2/Gemfile
[1621] + Gemfile in context: /home/nagao/run/app_nagao2/Gemfile
/home/nagao/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:313:in `check_for_activated_spec!': /home/nagao/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:313:in `check_for_activated_spec!': You have already activated puma 3.11.2, but your Gemfile requires puma 3.7.1. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
        from /home/nagao/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup'
        from /home/nagao/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/forwardable.rb:229:in `each'
        from /home/nagao/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/forwardable.rb:229:in `each'
```

---

(~/bin/run_app_nagao.sh)

```
#!/bin/sh
  cd /home/nagao/run/app_nagao2

rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
APP_NAGAO2_DATABASE_PASSWORD=******* SECRET_KEY_BASE=$(rails secret) RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true \
RAILS_ENV=production puma  -w 8
```

---

(~/rails-data/app_nagao2/Gemfile)抜粋

```
.
.
ruby '2.4.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7.0'
------------------------------------------------------
(~/rails-data/app_nagao2/config/puma.rb)
_proj_path = "#{File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)}"
_proj_name = File.basename(_proj_path)
_home = ENV.fetch("HOME") { "/home/nagao" }

pidfile "#{_home}/run/#{_proj_name}.pid"
bind "unix://#{_home}/run/#{_proj_name}.sock"
directory _proj_path


threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 8 }.to_i
threads threads_count, threads_count

# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests, default is 3000.
#
_environment_ = ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
if _environment_ == "development"
  port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
end
plugin :tmp_restart
```

---

```
xxxx@yyyy:~/rails-data/app_nagao2$ gem list | grep puma
```

### puma (3.11.2)

(rubyバージョン)
xxxx@yyyy:~$ ruby -v

### ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]

(railsバージョン)
xxxx@yyyy:~$ rails -v

### Rails 5.1.4

(gemバージョン)
xxxx@yyyy:~$ gem -v

### 2.7.4

Comment: 設定はあっていそうですけどね。Railsはどうやって動かしていますか？Unix Domain SocketはLISTENしていますかね？`netstat -ln | grep /home/nagao/run/app_nagao2.sock`

Comment: 検討ありがとうございます。サーバーログインから

Comment: * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 個のパッケージがアップデート可能です。
0 個のアップデートはセキュリティアップデートです。

Comment: Last login: Fri Jan 19 08:38:03 2018 from 192.168.210.4
nagao@****:~$ ./bin/run_app_nagao.sh
[1785] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[1785] * Version 3.11.0 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Love Song
[1785] * Min threads: 8, max threads: 8
[1785] * Environment: production
[1785] * Process workers: 8
[1785] * Phased restart available
[1785] * Listening on unix:///home/nagao/run/app_nagao2.sock
[1785] * Daemonizing...

nagao@***:~$ netstat -ln | grep /home/nagao/run/app_nagao2.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     24638    /home/nagao/run/app_nagao2.sock
nagao@nahs:~$

Comment: Pumaで動かしていて、ソケットもLISTENしてますね。すみません、僕にはわかりません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

改良の余地はありそうですが,いろいろやってみた結果
一応下記で正常にアプリは動いているようです。
どうもありがとうございました。

```
#!/bin/sh
APP_NAME=app_nagao2
USER=xxxxx
RAILS_ENV=production

cd /home/$USER/run/$APP_NAME

rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV
APP_NAGAO2_DATABASE_PASSWORD=***** SECRET_KEY_BASE=$(rails secret) RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true \
RAILS_ENV=$APP_NAME bundle exec puma -d -e production -C config/puma.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

あてずっぽうですが、タイムアウトしているとログに出ているので Nginx側のタイムアウトの設定をいじってみると何か変化ないでしょうか

```
   location /{
        proxy_pass http://app_nagao2; # アプリケーション名を記述
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 60s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_send_timeout 60s;
    }
```

Comment: レスありがとうございます。結果は同じでした。
最初言い忘れましたが「504 Gateway Time-out」は
1分以上ぐらい経って出ますからデフォルト値として
タイムアウト値は既に設定されていると思います。

Comment: もしapt-get upgrade実行前に戻せるなら
やってみたいと思いますが可能でしょうか。
今日(1/20)またパッケージアップデート
メッセージが出たので、ひょっとして
これで元に戻るかと期待したのですが
駄目でした。

Comment: Ubuntuのatp upgradeをロールバックする方法はわかりません。別の質問で出してもらえますか？ あと、当てずっぽうですが、Nginx側に問題はなくてRails側に問題が出てるんじゃないかと推測してます。apt-get upgrade で OS側のパッケージがアップデートされたのを追従するため gem 関係もアップデートする必要があるのかも。と思いました。Rails側のエラーログが出てないということですが、Pumaの設定と起動時のログを質問を編集して追記してもらえればトラブルシュートのお手伝いができるかもです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。すみません、返答もう少しお待ちください。nagao

Comment: 上記初期質問内容に【追加部分】として新たに付け加えました。